# List remove range by passing list as argument

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I have a list of missing items like this and I'm trying to perform a bulk operation against my DB table by taking out small chunks of items from the existing list (2500 items at a time):

```
 var castedItems = missingItems.ToList();
  while (castedItems.Any())
  {
    var subList = castedItems.Take(2500).ToList();
    DBRetry.Do(() => EFBatchOperation.For(ctx, 
    ctx.SearchedUserItems).InsertAll(subList), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    castedItems.RemoveRange(subList);           
  }
```

Missing items is a conccurrent bag , while casted  items are list. Now I should create an extension method which would accept the list that I took out and remove those 2500 items that were inserted into the database quickly... But I'm not quite sure how to do that ...

Can someone help me out?

P.S. The problematic part is this one:

```
castedItems.RemoveRange(subList);
```

It says that removerange only accepts two integers as arguments ( from and to ) :/

Comment: did you try passing the offset and limit? like 0 and 2500 first time?

Comment: something like this `castedItems.Except(subList).ToList();`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar do you mean like: castedItems=   castedItems.Except(subList).ToList(); ?

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha Can you show me an example ?

Comment: @User987: yes. you can do this `castedItems= castedItems.Except(subList).ToList();`

Comment: why not  simply do: castedItems.RemoveRange(0,2500);

Comment: @apomene or the example like Milind Anantwar shown , which one would be better?

Comment: @User987: The one that apomene shared :). As my solution iterates over the complete list and then removes the elements.

Comment: If you want to be removing items from the front of the collection you really ought to be using a Queue, not a list.  These operations are some of the most inefficient operations you can perform on a list.  A queue is specifically designed to do exactly this type of thing efficiently.  That's assuming you need to put the items into a new collection *at all*, rather than just iterating `missingItems` and never putting the items into a materialized question to begin with (which would be ideal if feasible).

Comment: @apomene can you post your final solution since this one seems to be the most efficient one ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can simply do:

```
castedItems.RemoveRange(0,2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var castedItems = missingItems.ToList();
var offset = 0;
var limit = 0;
  while (castedItems.Any())
  {
    var subList = castedItems.Take(2500).ToList();
limit = limit + 2500;
    DBRetry.Do(() => EFBatchOperation.For(ctx, 
    ctx.SearchedUserItems).InsertAll(subList), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    castedItems.RemoveRange(offset, limit);
offset = offset + limit?           
  }
```

Try this, offset limit updating might need to updated. Didn't check the working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a good compairer you can do Except.

```
castedItems = castedItems.Except(subList);
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2

That is the general case.  In your case you can use skip:

```
var castedItems = castedItems.Skip(2500);
```

Skip is the "reverse" of take.

Skip in this case is also much faster than RemoveRange or Except for two reasons,  no allocation is needed and it can be lazy.